# Why did Boeing choose to give the Boeing 720 such a designation?

Tags: aviation-history, aircraft-naming, boeing-707, boeing-720

The [Boeing 720](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_720) was a modification of the Boeing 707. Why was it given the unusual number of "720" instead of a "707-xxx" or "7x7" designation?

Answer (score 24):

Because the launch customer, United Airlines wanted it. From [Boeing frontiers](http://www.boeing.com/news/frontiers/archive/2004/february/i_history.html):

> The 720 was a ... first marketed to the airlines as the model 707-020. United Airlines was very interested in the 707-020 but had previously decided to go with Douglas and the DC-8. To help United avoid any negative public relations for going back to the 707, Boeing changed the name of the 707-020 to the 720.

According to [aviationweek](http://aviationweek.com/blog/farewell-boeings-720), the name change was at the behest of William ‘Pat’ Patterson, the president of launch customer United Airlines.

Comment: You'd think it would be negative PR for Douglas, but these decisions don't need to be rational...

Comment: @OrangeDog I really doubt that a company cares about the PR results for another company that performed below expectations, which is why I assumed United moved away from Douglas.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Exactly, it's not clear why Pat though that would be bad PR for United.

Comment: I would suppose they wanted to avoid the image of having bought sub-quality parts. If you found out  one of your suppliers your restaurant had an E-Coli outbreak, but you caught it in time to prevent it from getting to your shelves, you would still want to be discrete about switching suppliers even though it's their fault, not yours - your PR would still be effected. That's not to say necessarily that their was anything so drastically wrong with the DC-8, but it is an example where switching suppliers because there was a problem could be bad for PR.

Comment: On second thought, I doubt it was like that at all. I bet it was more analogous to a new iPhone launch. We don't think of new airplane launches quite the same now, they are mostly about efficiency and so forth. In the sixties, airplanes were advancing with speeds rivaling Moore's law. Imagine Apple launching an iPhone 4, having a lackluster performance or availability problems, and switching back to a slightly modified iPhone 3. Would they want to call it an iPhone 3? Would that be good for PR/sales?

Comment: @wedstrom continuing that digression, Intel's "Core" CPUs all trace their ancestry back to the Pentium Pro through Pentium 3 and *not* the Pentium 4, which turned out to be pretty much an evolutionary dead end. And yeah, in the process they re-branded and now "Pentium" is only used for low-end stuff.

Comment: @OrangeDog Some people just hate anything that could be interpreted as an admission that they were wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The 720 first flew before the 727 project began. At that time, there was no "7x7 series" – just the 707.

(The 717 passenger plane didn't come along until the 1990s, though the internal Boeing model number of what are usually called the C-135 Stratolifter and KC-135 Stratotanker was also 717, and that did exist at the time the 720 was produced.)